# How to avoid blinking when calling NavigateToString in WP7 Silverlight WebBrowser Control

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I need to render some Rich Text in the screen that needs to change following a timeline. In my iOS version I use the Web control and in Android version I use TextSpan.

I read some recommendations where people state that the WebControl is the best way to render rich text in Windows Phone 7 so I have a WebBrowser control that I populate with an HTML string. Everything works fine until I decide to programmatically change the content with a call to NavigateToString. The content gets changed but with a brief blink to a white screen in between.

As my program needs to update the contents of the WebBrowser control several times per second the screen turns all white from all the refreshes.

I am considering the painful idea of using TextBlocks with inline and LineBreaks but I will have to convert my HTML manually so I wanted to try to see if someone knows how to do this.

To replicate the issue just place a WebBrowser control on a page and update the content with NavigateToString to see the white transition blinking

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602132/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-webbrowser-control-before-l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do a combination of `OnNavigated` and javascript. I start with `Opacity = 0` and load a placeholder page into the control.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">function setContent(s) { document.body.innerHTML = s; } </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

In OnNavigated I set `Opacity = 1` then I use `InvokeScript` to load my actual content.

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("setContent", myContents);
```

In my case I am filling the entire page contents, though you might be able to write a more targetted piece of javascript if you are only changing certain pieces of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is normal because the WebBrowser control basically has to re-render the entire page, even if you changed small parts of the content. Your best choice would be using [RichTextBox](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-First-look-at-RichTextBox-control) - this will involve some manual text format processing.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest this:

```
WB_OnNavigating --> visibility = collapsed
WB_OnNavigated --> visibility = visible
```

Or a play on opacity. But these may be too slow given the multiple refreshes per second. Still may be worth a try to see what you get.

Is there any way the XAML background could be white or the HTML content's backcolor could match the page background?

Still looking for a better answer..

Comment: Also, consider this control from Component One .. still CTP though: http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/RichTextBoxPhone/

Comment: I tried opacity and visibility and the content does not appear either. Tried all combinations with the backgrounds but just a few updates per second make the content disappear due to the blinking

Comment: Using `Micorosft.Phone.Reactive` you could smooth out the changes using `Throttle().DistinctUntilChanged()`.