# Change background as well as foreground in webBrowser Control ( windows phone 8)?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm a newbie, and I want to make a book app.  I read file html in the Webbrowser (Windows Phone 8), but I want to change the background color to black and font color to white, but it is not working. I've tried following css,xaml.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,14,-10"  Background="Black">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="web" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="446" Loaded="web_Loaded" Height="215" Background="Black" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible as webbrowser engine renders a background color for HTML page. What you can use is a trick. As it is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602132/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-webbrowser-control-before-l), you can set default Opacity to 0, and when the load is completed, change the opacity to 1:

```
  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,14,-10"  Background="Black">
  <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="web" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Loaded="web_Loaded" Width="446" Height="215" Opacity="0" LoadCompleted="web_LoadCompleted"/>
  </Grid>

  private void web_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
     web.Opacity = 1;
  }
```

Or as it is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124166/how-to-make-webbrowser-control-with-black-background-in-windows-phone-7-1) you can cover webbrowser with another element which you collapse when content rendering is finished.