# WP WebBrowser black background

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

Is there any way that I can change the default white background color of the Windows Phone WebBrowser control to black. By background color I am referring to the color that is displayed while loading and when over scrolled in any direction. I have tried every possible color setting on the control including background and foreground color but they don't seems to be having any effect. Is this even possible? I doubt if the trick of displaying a black page will work because I am displaying pages with black backgrounds but the white areas are displayed while a page is loading and when a user periodically scrolls further than a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is not really a way to change the background color of the WebBrowser component and the only way to get it black while loading is to either make it transparent or display a black block in front of it whilst loading. Another thing I discovered though is that the white background you see when over scrolling is not part of the native browser component and is actually caused by the WPF wrapper. I discovered the existence of the wrapper after reading http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html. After much trial and error I determined that by changing the background colors of all the Border elements that make up the WebBrowser component it is possible to change the color that is shown while over scrolling. The code I ended up with is something modified from the code on the post:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using LinqToVisualTree;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace InvertBrowser
{
    class WebBrowserHelper
    {
        private WebBrowser _browser;

        public bool ScrollDisabled { get; set; }

        public WebBrowserHelper(WebBrowser browser)
        {
            _browser = browser;
            browser.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(browser_Loaded);
        }

        private void browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<DependencyObject> borders = _browser.Descendants<Border>();

            foreach (var o in borders)
            {
                var ding = o as Border;
                ding.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for hiding the WebBrowser compoenent whilst loading can easily be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme for background color in a code behind file but you will have to make sure that when the user changes their default theme to light your control's background will change accordingly. Check out the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) about working with themes.

Comment: I am sorry but I have absolutely no idea how this helps, could you possibly elaborate on it?

Comment: Change the background theme of the app to suit your needs and change it back when the app exits.

Comment: I doubt that will work because my phone currently has the dark theme yet the WebBrowser still has a white background. The background of the application itself is black though.

Comment: I was suggesting what is mentioned at the end of the article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545%28v=vs.105%29.aspx and if it does not work then keep on digging. Good luck.

Comment: I am truly sorry but you have to be more specific because I cannot find anything of use in that entire article. The article merely covers how you can bind properties to theme colors and adapt the colors of elements to different themes. That could be useful had I known what property on the WebBrowser would change its background color but unfortunately I don't.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible as webbrowser engine renders a background color for HTML page. What you can use is a trick. You can set default Opacity to 0, and when the load is completed, change the opacity to 1:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="10"  Background="Black">
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="web" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="200" Opacity="0" LoadCompleted="web_LoadCompleted"/>
</Grid>

private void web_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   web.Opacity = 1;
}
```

You can find some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602132/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-webbrowser-control-before-l). Another solution is to cover webbrowser with [other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124166/how-to-make-webbrowser-control-with-black-background-in-windows-phone-7-1).

Comment: Thanks, I have though of something like that to solve the loading problem but it won't solve the over scrolling problem. Are you saying that I'm simply stuck on that one?

Comment: You are right, that won't help with scrolling. As I have not worked with that, I don't have ideas. I saw once blog with suppression of scrolling: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html - but I doubt it will help in this case.

Comment: If I can eliminate the internal over scrolling then I can place it on a black scrollviewer to give the same effect, just in black

Comment: I heve not plwyed with that, but good luck and happy new year :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. It seems as if the link you posted might be very useful in achieving this.